# How to complie SBA (sparse bundle adjustment) using Mex in Matlab

Tags: matlab, mex

I tried to use the open tool sba to do sparse bundle adjustment in Matlab version. However, I always failed in compiling it no matter what. Could anyone help? My problems are exactly as same as the given webpage :http://newsreader.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/285415

Thanks,
Han